# Incorrect values when using an object used in a dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll

my project worked perfectly well when I used an old version of a library. I wanted to upgrade for some features and some important bugfixes, so I fetched the new version, compiled it, linked with my project in VS2012, and now I am getting a really weird runtime error with objects and structures used in the dll.

They seem fine from my exe, but when I set a breakpoint in the dll the values are wrong. I tried recompiling both solutions, restarting my computer, setting both projects to 32 bits, same character encoding, but still I have those errors.

Here is a screenshot (both structures are the same in the dll and the exe, and they point to the same address):

[image: Error]

Object creation works well (didn't have any problem with the objects I created), it is just parameter passing between the dll and the exe.

Comment: Smells like different structure packing between projects - the default changed between various Visual Studio versions, so check the project properties to make sure everything is consistent (Project properties->C++->Code generation->Struct Member Alignment).

Comment: @RogerRowland Both are 32 bits and use the same value (Default), I am using more than 10 libraries and I don't have the source for some of them, so I don't think changing that would be a good idea. I just rebooted (the last think that seemed reasonable) and I am recompiling everything.